# Why are constants not accessible from a python file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, constants, databricks

In my `Databricks` project, I have a very basic notebook which contains some constants as below:

```
RAW_FOLDER_PATH = 'dbfs:/mnt/formuleinsstorage/rawdata/unziped/'
PROCESSED_FOLDER_PATH = 'dbfs:/mnt/formuleinsstorage/processeddata'
MESSAGE_TO_WHEN_COMPLETING_NOTEBOOK_SUCCESSFULLY = 'Success'

dbutils.notebook.exit(MESSAGE_TO_WHEN_COMPLETING_NOTEBOOK_SUCCESSFULLY)
```

and then i need to run this notebook as part of another notebook using this code:

```
dbutils.notebook.run("./../helpers/configuration", 0)
dbutils.notebook.run("./../helpers/functions", 0)
```

Although, it looks like the `dbutils.notebook.run()` in the second notebook is successful, but when i try to get the value of `RAW_FOLDER_PATH` in the second notebook it gives me the below error:

```
NameError: name 'RAW_FOLDER_PATH' is not defined
```

I tried to run the same code using :

`%run "./../helpers/configuration"` and it was successful.

But, if i try to run 2 magic commands **in one cell**, such as below:

%run "./../helpers/configuration"
%run "./../helpers/configuration"

it fails with the below error:

```
Failed to parse %run command: string matching regex `\$[\w_]+' expected but `%' found. If notebook path contains spaces, wrap with double quotes.

Stacktrace:
  /ingestions/ingest_circuite_file: python
```

So, how can i run 2 magic commands in 1 cell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the section "Comparison of %run and notebook workflows" [here](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#comparison-of-run-and-notebook-workflows). In particular, `dbutils.notebook.run()` runs the other notebook in a new job, so it gets executed but not in the same kernel as the calling notebook. If you want the second notebook's variables to be visible from the calling notebook, you should use `%run` instead, as in `%run ./../helpers/configuration`.

Edit in response to comment: You'll need to put each `%run` command in a separate cell. Per the Databricks [documentation](https://docs.gcp.databricks.com/notebooks/share-code.html#use-run-to-import-a-notebook): "`%run` must be in a cell by itself, because it runs the entire notebook inline."

Comment: Updated the answer to address this followup question.

Comment: please find the updated question !

Comment: As I said in my updated answer, you can't put multiple `%run` commands in one cell. Instead you should put the commands in two separate cells.